# Yum upgrade php error how to read

Tags: yum, php5

I am trying to upgrade php from 5.3 to 5.6 on centos 6.8.

I am using Remi repo and have followed the instructions there. 
However on running:

`yum upgrade "php*"`

i get the errors here http://pastebin.com/HFKg1paG

Can anyone give me an indication of why this is failing as i am struggling to debug based on the error info provided.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uuid-php is not compatible with newer php version.

- If you really need it, you cannot update.
- If you can remove it, you will be able to update.

Tips: [php-pecl-uuid](https://pecl.php.net/package/uuid) provides an alternative implementation which is compatible with all recent PHP versions.